# trying to return an union of two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to return a new Array containing unique values from both first and second array in the order they appear.

So far I have:

```
function union(first, second) {
return first.filter(function(value) {
  return second.indexOf(value) === -1;
})

.concat(second.filter(function(value){
  return first.indexOf(value) === -1;
}))
}
```

The results should look like this:

```
union([2, 1], [2, 3]);
// -> [2, 1, 3]
union(['html', 'css', 'javascript'], ['php', 'css', 'sql']);
// -> ["html", "css", "javascript", "php", "sql"]
union(
  ['a', 'link', 'to', 'the', 'past'],
  ['the', 'adventure', 'of', 'link']
)
```

Comment: By union, people might think you need to combine two arrays. I guess you might be looking for the difference between the two arrays instead of the union.

Comment: @MwibutsaFloribert no the OP is looking for union. Notice the concat operation

Comment: @americanguy93 you don't need to deal with this, you can just do ```[...new Set([...array1, ...array2])]``` to get the union

Comment: hev1 has given a nicer solution. The issue with your thing btw was that you were removing the duplicates from both arrays

Answer (score 10):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge both arrays and then pass it to the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) constructor, which only retains unique values.

```js
function union(first, second) {
  return [...new Set([...first, ...second])];
}
console.log(union([2, 1], [2, 3]));
console.log(union(['html', 'css', 'javascript'], ['php', 'css', 'sql']));
console.log(union(
  ['a', 'link', 'to', 'the', 'past'],
  ['the', 'adventure', 'of', 'link']
));
```

Comment: Looking at this just blew my mind. I had no idea spread syntax could be used to instantiate a set of elements in an array. It's gonna take me a little while to realize how much code I can refactor haha

Comment: @joshstrike Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Short way,

```
let first = ['html', 'css', 'javascript']
let second = ['php', 'css', 'sql']
var union = [...new Set([...first, ...second])];
console.log(union);

// union = [ 'html', 'css', 'javascript', 'php', 'sql' ]
```